# How can I Change the cellClass on columnResized?

Tags: ag-grid-react

How can I Change the `cellClass` in `onColumnResized` function?
Example: when the size of the column increases or decreases `cellClass` should be change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare a global Boolean variable
2. Initialize it to false
3. Now write a function for `onColumnResized`
4. Set the variable as *!(variable_name)*. So, in this way first time on column resize this variable will be set to true and next time it will be set to false.
5. Now use `cellClassRules` instead of cellClass and write a function where you check whether this variable is true or false using a ternary condition. If true apply one class, if false apply another class.
6. Mention the styles for those classes in css file.

**PS:** The reason why I have asked you to use cellClassRules instead of cellClass is:

***cellClass***: All new classes are applied. Old classes are not removed so be aware that classes will accumulate. If you want to remove old classes, then use cellClassRules.
***cellClassRules***: Rules that return true will have the class applied the second time. Rules tha return false will have the class removed second time.